# Stop Printing double values SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

### **Hello Guys!**

Oracle SQL

I am trying to find a way to stop my sql Query print duplicate values.

For example Results coming for a table are:

```
Nikos
Nikos
Nikos
Tony
Tony
```

The result I want:

```
Nikos
Tony
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: `select distinct ...`?

Comment: As others said, DISTINCT is _probably_ the solution.  However, I'd ask you to re-read your post, then consider ... can you debug code that you cannot see?  No?  Then don't expect others to do so.

Comment: Okay! But you don't have to be ironic. We all start from somewhere. Have a good day!

Comment: It's possible that the duplicates are due to an incorrect join condition, in which case you might need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate values :

```
SELECT DISTINCT col
FROM table t;
```